# Backbone - connecting $el.html to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following code in a Backbone View javascript file:

```
var addPlayerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    model: Player,
    id: 'addPlayerDiv',

    initialize: function() {
        console.log('addPlayerView has been created');
        //this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
    },

    render: function (){
        this.$el.html('<div class="container"></div><div id="myform"><b>Add New Player to Roster for Team X</b><form>'
        +'<p><input type="text" name="player[firstName]" value="First Name">'
        +'<p><input type="text" name="player[lastName]" value="Last Name"><p>'
        +'<input type="text" name="player[age]" value="Age"><p>'
        +'<input type="text" name="player[shirtNumber]" value="Shirt Number"><p>'
        +'<input type="text" name="player[email]" value="Email"><p>'
        +'<input type="text" name="player[phone]" value="Phone"><p>'
        +'<input type="submit" value="Submit"><FORM><INPUT Type="button" VALUE="Cancel" onClick="addThePlayer(event)"></FORM></form>'
        +'</div></div>');
        return this;
    }
});
```

Two questions.

(1) Is there a better way than just dumping all the html code inside the this.$el.html function? That's really ugly.

(2) How do I attach functions to the HTML code inside the this.$el.html function? Is it just hardcoded in there? How do I pass the "addThePlayer(event)" function my player data?

This is crazy. I am groping around in the dark.

Comment: Have you tried putting that into the template?

Comment: I will try that - is a template a solution to both questions?

Comment: You can do that with backbone model and pass it to the view like with nay other backbone view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (1) Is there a better way than just dumping all the html code inside
>   the this.$el.html function? That's really ugly.

Yes. Just move the HTML code to a template. Mixing HTML with JavaScript is, as you say, ugly, and also error-prone. For instance, there are a couple of problems in your HTML markup, one being you have one `<form>` within another `<form>`.
So, define a template using `<script type="text/html"></script>`:

```
<script type="text/html" id="player-template">

    <div class="container">
        <b>Add New Player to Roster for Team X</b>
        <form id="myform">
            <p>
                <input type="text" name="player[firstName]" value="First Name" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="text" name="player[lastName]" value="Last Name" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="text" name="player[age]" value="Age" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="text" name="player[shirtNumber]" value="Shirt Number" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="text" name="player[email]" value="Email" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="text" name="player[phone]" value="Phone" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                <input type="button" value="Cancel" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>

</script>
```

Then, in your `addPlayerView`, use this template, like this:

```
render: function () {
    var playerTemplate = document.getElementById('player-template').innerHTML;
    this.$el.html(_.template(playerTemplate)());
}
```

---

> (2) How do I attach functions to the HTML code inside the
>   this.$el.html function? Is it just hardcoded in there? How do I pass
>   the "addThePlayer(event)" function my player data?

Define a property `events` in your view and attach a callback function for when you submit the form.

```
events: {
    'submit #myform': 'onAddPlayer'
},

//
onAddPlayer: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // so that the form is not actually submitted.

    var $form = $(event.currentTarget);

    var data = $form.serialize(); // <-- this is where you have your player data.
}
```

---

> (3) How to handle a click on the cancel button?

Why your code `'cancel #myform': 'cancelAddPlayer'` does not work while my identical code for `submit` does is because the latter is [a standard jQuery event](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) for when a form is submitted. **There is no event called `cancel`**. Therefore, you simply need to handle a click on the cancel button, and for that you use the following syntax: `'click #cancel-add': 'cancelPlayerAdd'`. So, to wrap things up, your events property should look like this:

```
events: {
    'submit #myform': 'onPlayerAdd',
    'click #cancel-add': 'cancelPlayerAdd' // <-- THIS.
}
```

Do not forget to define the function `onCancelPlayerAdd`!

And the cancel button will be getting the identifier `cancel-add`:

```
<input type="button" id="cancel-add" value="Cancel" />
```

It would not hurt to get familiar with [the events supported in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/).

Comment: Thanks so much, this works great. One problem I have now is that I can 'destroy()' the view after submitting it, but then I can't show the same view again - I can only show it once. The second problem is that I don't know how to 'cancel' the view - meaning - I want to put this  "events: {
        'submit #myform': 'onAddPlayer',
        'cancel #myform': 'cancelAddPlayer'
    }" but the cancel doesn't work. It would really help me if you could advise me on these, thanks!!

Comment: @AlexMills As for the first part. How do you show the view in the first place? Please share your code. You will need to create a new instance of the view to show it, like this: `new addPlayerView()`. As for how to handle cancelling, see the 3rd part of the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create a template
Something like this:

```
var template = _.template('<div class="container"></div><div id="myform"><b>Add New Player to Roster for Team X</b><form>'
        +'<p><input type="text" name="<%player[firstName]%>" value="First Name">'
        +'<p><input type="text" name="<%player[lastName]%>" value="Last Name"><p>'
        +'<input type="text" name="<%player[age]%>" value="Age"><p>'
        +'<input type="text" name="<%player[shirtNumber]%>" value="Shirt Number"><p>'
        +'<input type="text" name="<%player[email]%>" value="Email"><p>'
        +'<input type="text" name="<%player[phone]%>" value="Phone"><p>'
        +'<input type="submit" value="Submit"><FORM><INPUT Type="button" class="InputButton" VALUE="Cancel" "></FORM></form>'
        +'</div></div>')
this.$el.html(template(player));
```

For the "addThePlayer" function, the best thing to do is to create events object inside the view.
Something like this will work:

```
  events: {
    "click InputButton"         : "addThePlayer",
  },
```

Hope this helps :).

Comment: Why are you using template markup (`<%player[firstName]%>`) in the template? I think that `name` attribute is supposed to be just the string `player[firstName]`. Even if substitution was called for you'd want to use `<%= ... %>` instead of the evaluation syntax (`<% ... %>`).